# jolt transform different level objects

Tags: json, merge, jolt

I need help to transform json objects. I think maybe firstly transform "array" to flat structure and then zip somehow keys from "keySets" with keys in "array".

Input:

```json
{
  "entities": [
    {
      "name": "posts",
      "keySets": [
        "MATERIALS",
        "LOCATIONS"
      ],
      "arraySize": 0,
      "array": {}
    },
    {
      "name": "owner",
      "keySets": [
        "IDS"
      ],
      "arraySize": 1,
      "array": {
        "e58442c8-7498-4c2e-bb55-3d06fb5fd00c": "TM0100"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "orders",
      "keySets": [
        "MATERIALS",
        "LOCATIONS"
      ],
      "arraySize": 6,
      "array": {
        "80365028": {
          "2585": true,
          "7035": true,
          "B275": true,
          "B341": true,
          "B680": false,
          "B340": true
        }
      }
    },
   {
      "name": "rules",
      "keySets": [
        "MATERIALS",
        "LOCATIONS",
        "LOCATIONS"
      ],
      "arraySize": 8,
      "array": {
        "80277271": {
            "B340": {
               "8503": true
             },
             "1626": {
               "B275": true,
               "B341": true,
               "7035": true             
              },
              "1702": {
                  "B275": true,
                  "B341": true,
                  "7035": true,
                  "B340": true                 
             }
         }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I'd like to get output like this (elemValue can also be string and number):

```json
{
  "entities": [
    {
      "name": "posts",
      "value": []
    },
    {
      "name": "owner",
      "value": [
        {
          "key": {
            "IDS": "e58442c8-7498-4c2e-bb55-3d06fb5fd00c"
          },
          "elemValue": "TM0100"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "orders",
      "value": [
        {
          "key": {
            "MATERIALS": "80365028",
            "LOCATIONS": "2585"
          },
          "elemValue": "true"
        },
        {
          "key": {
            "MATERIALS": "80365028",
            "LOCATIONS": "7035"
          },
          "elemValue": "true"
        },
        {
          "key": {
            "MATERIALS": "80365028",
            "LOCATIONS": "B275"
          },
          "elemValue": "true"
        },
        {
          "key": {
            "MATERIALS": "80365028",
            "LOCATIONS": "B680"
          },
          "elemValue": "false"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "rules",
      "value": [
        {
          "key": {
            "MATERIALS": "80277271",
            "LOCATIONS": "8503"
          },
          "elemValue": "true"
        },
        {
          "key": {
            "MATERIALS": "80277271",
            "LOCATIONS": "B275"
          },
          "elemValue": "true"
        },
        {
          "key": {
            "MATERIALS": "80277271",
            "LOCATIONS": "B341"
          },
          "elemValue": "true"
        },
        {
          "key": {
            "MATERIALS": "80277271",
            "LOCATIONS": "B275"
          },
          "elemValue": "true"
        },
        {
          "key": {
            "MATERIALS": "80277271",
            "LOCATIONS": "B341"
          },
          "elemValue": "false"
        },
        {
          "key": {
            "MATERIALS": "80277271",
            "LOCATIONS": "7025"
          },
          "elemValue": "true"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm very newbie with jolt. I've tried to flatten firstly and then combine.
One of my attempt when I extract top level property. But I don't know how to apply this for every level in the object:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "entities": {
        "*": {
          "array": {
            "*": {
              "$": "entities.[&3].&2.key",
              "@": "entities.[&3].&2.value"
            }
          },
          "*": "entities.[&1].&"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```